# MongoDB multiple scalable collections

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I'm using morphia to connect to mongoDB. I'm collecting daily mileage for cars. Right now, all daily mileage for all cars are stored in 1 collection with the following attribute: 
plateNumber, date, mileage

we want to store the daily mileages from all the way back in 1990 onwards. Right now, we're already maintaining around 4500+ cars (that's roughly 1.3 mil records a year). We're trying with one year worth of data, and the performance is already slagging really badly. I was thinking of splitting the storage into multiple collections based on the plate number. so each plate number will have its own collection named after the plate number. I need some ideas. Is there any other way to solve this?

Adding details:
How we'll use the data: we want to query mileages of multiple cars (sometimes per department, or per geographic area, per make/model, etc) at any given date range.
So, lets just say we want to monitor mileages in a suburb, we'll take all plate numbers' mileages operating in that suburb from 01 Jan 2014 to 23 Jun 2014 and perform calculation on the data.

thanks.

Comment: You might want to use bulk insert for old data, which is vastly faster than sequential inserts.

Comment: ok, but how frequently do you want to run these queries? I mean will the individual car owners be able to run them or at any given time or you'll do it overnight to make some statistics available for a week or so. Also 1.3 mil records don't seem too much so I am surprised that your performance is bad. What kind of indexes do you have on the collection?

Comment: index is on plateNumber and date (composite index). Insertion won't be a problem, since it will be done only once a year at the end of the year. The retrieval will be quite intensive. Queries will be frequently be made for monitoring purposes. and that's just one year. when it's 10 years, it will be 13 mil+, and so on.

Comment: Can you try out how fast is it for just plate number + date compared to including other parameters? It is also important how do you construct the query since that decides if your index will or won't be used. Maybe it is enough to extend the composite index/define the queries in another way.

Comment: Maybe you can show us the result of the `getIndexes()` and one or two example queries with some example `documents` from the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what is your configuration you can try [Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) or you may attempt to [Partition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16532/collection-partitioning-in-mongodb) your db -- though this approach is `hybrid`, meaning that you would mimic partitioning from sql database systems (Oracle, Sql Server, etc.).

Also note that if you `insert` (basically append) a lot of entries to a single file it will gradually become slow since mongo needs to update the `primary key` (`mongoID`) that needs to be unique + if you defined other indexes on the `collection` those also need to be updated.

If you can provide more information on how you intend to use the collected data and in what time intervals + are these operations online or offline I'll update my answer.